# Hard time using Scala Worksheets in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm following the course Functional Programming Principles in Scala
but I am experiencing a lot of issues when using Scala Worksheets in IntelliJ to make quick tests.

For example, I have set up a new Scala project where I have created a package object called `lecture5` (it's in the file) `src/main/scala/lecture5/package.scala`

The content of the file is:

```scala
package object lecture5 {

  def last[T](xs:List[T]): T =  xs match {
    case List() => throw new Error("empty list")
    case List(x) => x
    case x :: y => last(y)
  }

  /* init should return all elements but last */
  def init[T](xs: List[T]): List[T] = xs match {
    case List() => throw new Error("List is empty")
    case List(x) => List[T]()
    case y :: ys => y :: init(ys)
  }

  def concat[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = xs match {
      case List() => ys
      case z:: zs => z :: concat(zs, ys)
    }
}
```

In the worksheet I have the following:

```scala
import lecture5._


val x = List("a","b","c")

val xs = List("a","b")
val ys = List("c")

last(x)

init(x)

concat(xs, ys) == x
```

In the settings for the worksheet I checked `Interactive Mode`, `Make project before run` and use `Run Type = REPL` (`Plain` doesn't work for some reason) and `Compiler profile = Default`.

When I click on the "`play`" button to run the worksheet the functions `init` and `last` work, but for the function `concat` I get error:

```
Error:(13, 9) not found: value concat
concat(xs, ys) == x
```

Why is `concat` not found?

Note that if I use the Scala console from within the `sbt-shell` and execute the same commands then everything works.

How can I configure IntelliJ to work with a Worksheet without issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replicated the issue on IntelliJ 2019.1.2, Scala Plugin 2019.1.8. No form of building the project before running the worksheet worked. Package object was finally successfully imported after `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`. A workaround that seems to work for me without restarting is to use Scala `Scratch file` instead of `Scala Worksheet`:

```
Right click project | New | Scratch file | Scala
```

Possibly related to issue [SCL-12890](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12890)