# Importing classes into Scala worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In my scala worksheet test.sc I define :

```
import com.tradedata.VolatilityInstance
```

test.sc exists at src/main/scala

In location src/main/scala I define :

```
package com.tradedata

class VolatilityInstance(intervalLength: Int, volatility: Double, beginDate: String, endDate: String) {

  override def toString: String = {
    this.beginDate
  }

}
```

The filename for this class is `VolatilityData.scala`

`VolatilityData.scala` exists at level src/main/scala/com/tradedata

When I attempt to run the worksheet I receive error :

```
Error:(1, 16) object VolatilityInstance is not a member of package com.tradedata
import com.tradedata.VolatilityInstance
```

If i define a new Scala object :

```
import com.tradedata.VolatilityInstance

object Tester extends App {

}
```

Tester object runs without issue.

I've tried re-building the project, invalidating the caches and restarting IntelliJ but cannot fix.

Is this a bug with the Scala worksheet ? How to import other classes into the Scala worksheet ?

Comment: There are indeed few open issues along those lines, for example https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12890. As a workaround try [Scratch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56207258/5205022)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I've tested your case in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3 (Ultimate Edition) with Scala plugin 2019.2.28*

Open `test.sc`, click `Scala worksheet settings` and change `Run type` from `REPL` to `Plain`.

Answer (score 0):

In `Worksheet Settings` check `Build project before run`

It helps me